# Htaccess: SetEnvIF List read from a TXT file?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have a collectively very long list of black listed IPs (for different reasons). Something like this (just an example):

```
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "1.2.100.*" DenyIP
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "2.3.4.*" DenyIP
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "123.123.*.*" DenyIP
..
..
..
..
..
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "200.200.*.*" DenyIP

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=DenyIP
```

It is working, but about **200 lines** long.

### Question

How do I put all these lines (`SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "<ip>" DenyIP`) inside a TXT file, and then load it inside `.htaccess` so that I could do the same `Deny from env=DenyIP` again, please?

**Note**: For some reasons, I need it for the `.htaccess` approach. Not able to put inside VirtualHost Config settings.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this on `.htaccess`. The [`Include`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include) directive only works in server config, virtual host and directory contexts. You either have it directly in `.htaccess` or include it in the `<Directory>` block.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    . . .
    <Directory /path/to/directory>
        Include /path/to/your/SetEnvIfs.conf
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from env=DenyIP
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you for the Server Config approach. Got 2 questions now. (1) does that `Include <file>` approach works for the list of rules like `SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "1.2.3.*" DenyIP`? (2) If I use this, will the existing `.htaccess` file inside the docroot still work please? Or be ignored?

Comment: [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) controls that, not the presence of `<Directory>` block.